# Bootstrap 3 - 4 column grid breaking if height is not the same

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have responsive images in a 4 column layout with the same column height, but for some reason the images are breaking the entire layout if I don't set a specific height for them.

You can see the live working example here: http://atelierdunoir.aphelion.ga/reader/directory/

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
 <div class="container section-headline-wrap">
    <div class="section-headline">
      <h3>Oneshot Directory</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container hb-container" id="containera">

      <div class="row hb-row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <hr>
        </div>
     <?php
     foreach ($comics as $key => $comic) {
     echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">';
     if($comic->get_thumb(true)) echo '<div class="thumbnail"><img class="img-
    responsive" src="'.$comic->get_thumb(true).'" />';
    echo '<div class="caption"><h4>' . $comic->name . '</h4>'; 
    echo '<div class="panel-footer"><a href="'. $comic->href() .'" class="btn btn-default btn-block">View Project</a></div></div></div></div>';
    }

echo prevnext('directory/', $comics);
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm using a comic software here: https://foolcode.github.io/FoOlSlide/

But this a custom theme that I'm working on.

Any ideas on how to have the same column height with responsive images? **All images have been resized to 680px in height, but the widths vary.**

Comment: I suggest you need to use https://github.com/kombai/freewall

Comment: use http://kombai.github.io/freewall/example/pinterest-layout.html example its really easy to use.